# Will butternut squash ripen if taken off the vine?

Tags: vines, harvesting, squash, ripening

The vine is dying for some reason and there are a lot of squash on it. Will they ripen if taken off the dying vine or should I just leave them on the vine to lay in the sun on the dying vine?

Comment: You gotta send pictures and more information.  If this is blight, a systemic fungus, then no, your fruit will be worthless.  We need to ID your problem first and foremostest!  When we experience mistakes and do not use them to learn enough to not make that mistake again we will be repeating those mistakes...Please send pictures and stuff like where you live, what you have already added, like fertilizers, composts, what kind of composts if any you've used, have you ever done a soil test, what are your watering techniques and any thing you've added to the soil to perhaps 'feed plants'?

Comment: Sally, welcome! @stormy is right - pictures help *a lot*, and so does every bit of information we can get. You can always [edit] your post to include more details. Let me also encourage you to take the [tour] and browse our [help], that’s a goid way to get a general overview of the site’s mechanisms & rules.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you could cure the plant of whatever ails it, but if that's not possible, you can try ripening them off  the vine by 'curing', see here https://homeguides.sfgate.com/ripen-butternut-squash-after-picking-78973.html. Whether its worth the effort is another matter - your squash will not be so tasty as those which are fully ripe when cut.

Comment: Hey Bamboo, do you see a need at all for a simple questionnaire for OPs to answer along with their question?  I am so tired of trying to help based on a question that shows the poor OPs don't know enough to formulate a question with which to get help.

Comment: @stormy Yes and no; I do think G&L is a special case on SE because it deals mostly with living things, and advice on how to ask a question should definitely include location, how long they've had/planted the plant, whether its in a pot or the ground, and photos, but each case is different, and too much insistence on a  lot of info might stop people asking at all...We know what info we need for each case, but they don't and likely can't know, and to some extent, answers are very much tailored to the problem they (and we) are seeing

Comment: A short, concise, questionnaire would only help formulate questions.  Every SINGLE case is different but every single case needs a stable foundation that is necessary to know before being responsibly able to answer questions.  You of all people know more than this site's statistics how often you ask "Where in the World do you live"...etc.  I also am certain that a SMALL, short,  little questionnaire will help the OP formulate the question and teach how to think about plants ATST.

Comment: @stormy - seems we're in agreement then about the four essential components!

Comment: 4 essential components?  You mean for questions?  Absolutely!  Just 4 questions would vastly streamline our conversations and time spent answering.  I HATE touching anything twice that could have been taken care of in the first few steps.  Most people have so little knowledge about plants, heck biology, soils...how everything works together.  Just asking them basic questions we need to answer as well as TEACH would and could be very exciting for OPs!  Visiting other sites, this problem is glaringly obvious as well.  Be nice to have POP QUIZZES, to make sure they understood our answers.  LOL

Comment: I have noticed an awful lot that when the OP repeats back what they are going to do they DON'T understand what they've been tasked to do.  Have you?

Comment: @stormy not sure I have noticed that, but then I don't take much interest in what people do after I;'ve dished out advice - I see my part as giving out the information as clearly and accurately as possible- theirs is to follow it... or not, that's their choice.. Nice if they take it on board, but whether they do or not is not my business, or at least, that's my philosophy in life, generally. I'm more like a signpost saying go this way, but there  are other roads they can choose... if they want, so I don;t attach to the outcome.

Comment: Whoa @Bamboo your philosophy is  beautiful.  I have worked all my life to not become so invested.  I can tell that you have worked very hard to compartmentalize and have done a bit better than moi...teaching others always highlighted the fact that others know zippo or what they think they know has to be augmented somewhat.  Making gardeners, sounds so sappy, is a beautiful thing.  The biggest problem I am seeing are humans who want, no, need to control.  To the detriment of pets, plants and inhibiting the goal of loving, understanding the out of doors.  Being able to willingly learn to garden.

Comment: @stormy Not sure its compartmentalizing - its about boundaries, knowing what's mine and what's someone else's, where the edges are really. Everyone has a right to make a choice, and they usually exercise it (myself included) regardless of any well informed advice they ask for or are offered. Even so, that's no reason not to offer advice! But the choices others make are up to them... As for making gardeners, well, not everyone's made the same way, they may  have other areas that inflame their passions instead.

Comment: Of course, but every human in my opinion would be healthier if they had some knowledge, thus some contact with plants and soil.  Makes me grin about the consternation of bosses when I insisted on education not selling.  I never lost a single bid/presentation.  Once, however, after a huge presentation using lots of plans and drawings, the lady of the house who was so very excited and happy to do my plans...she asked me, "What is this Flower"?  As she is pointing to a tree on the plan.  Since then, I am very into making sure others aren't doing the bobble head thing not knowing the plans at all.